# Giving a home directory a specific "bit set" using chmod

Tags: chmod, finger

the finger man page says I need to use chmod to give the home directory the "other-users-execute bit set", in order to restrict finger requests to only those that original from the local host as a security measure,but I cant find that in the chmod man page, is this very straight forward or is there other material I need to cover to understand what is happening there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context here is presumably this section of the `finger` manpage:

> `~/.nofinger`
>
> If finger finds this file in a user's home directory, it will, for finger requests originating outside the local host, firmly deny the existence of that user.  For this to work, the finger program, as started by `fingerd(8)`, must be able to see the `.nofinger` file. This generally means that the home directory containing the file must have the other-users-execute bit set (o+x). See `chmod(1)`.  If you use this feature for privacy, please test it with “finger @localhost” before relying on it, just in case.

Once you know how `chmod` works, this tells you what to do: `chmod o+x /path/to/home/directory`. As a regular user, you can do this as follows:

```
cd
chmod o+x .
```

Root can change all home directories:

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/*/
```

In [the GNU `chmod` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html), the following paragraphs explain this:

> The format of a symbolic mode is `[ugoa...][[-+=][perms...]...]`, where *perms* is either zero or more letters from the set `rwxXst`, or a single letter from the set `ugo`.  Multiple symbolic modes can be given, separated by commas.
>
> A combination of the letters `ugoa` controls which users' access to the file will be changed: the user who owns it (`u`), other users in the file's group (`g`), other users not in the file's group (`o`), or all users (`a`).  If none of these are given, the effect is as if (`a`) were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.
>
> The operator `+` causes the selected file mode bits to be added to the existing file mode bits of each file; `-` causes them to be removed; and `=` causes them to be added and causes unmentioned bits to be removed except that a directory's unmentioned set user and group ID bits are not affected.
>
> The letters `rwxXst` select file mode bits for the affected users: read (`r`), write (`w`), execute (or search for directories) (`x`), execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (`X`), set user or group ID on execution (`s`), restricted deletion flag or sticky bit (`t`).  Instead of one or more of these letters, you can specify exactly one of the letters `ugo`: the permissions granted to the user who owns the file (`u`), the permissions granted to other users who are members of the file's group (`g`), and the permissions granted to users that are in neither of the two preceding categories (`o`).

Comment: That's not really quite correct. The `finger` daemon runs without any special permissions, so `chmod o+x` only facilitates `fingerd` if the previous permissions were `o=`. This can vary from system to system, or by Linux distribution.

Comment: @roaima I’m afraid I don’t understand what you’re saying. `chmod o+x` sets the bit in any case; so after it’s run, `fingerd` will be able to check for the existence of `.nofinger`, irrespective of what the permissions were before (and yes, `fingerd` might have already been able to do this).

Comment: If the permissions were already `o=rx` (as on Debian, for example) then the `chmod` operation is a no-op. However, on RHEL-derived systems IIRC the default is `o=` so the `chmod o+x` is necessary for `fingerd` to be able to search for the file `~/.nofinger`

Comment: Yes, but I still don’t understand how that makes the answer (or the manpage) “not really quite correct”. It’s just as easy to run `chmod o+x` as it is to check for the permission before deciding whether to run `chmod o+x`, isn’t it? And in any case, `chmod o+x` results in a configuration which works — which doesn’t say *anything* about whether it worked before the `chmod`.

Comment: shortly after posting this question I found this page which is proving to also be very helpful http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/SetUserID.html

Comment: My O.S is indeed Debian, and the finger man page paragraph I was referring to did say the chmod command was required for fingerd to be able to see the .nofinger file in the home directory, so I don't know if this helps clarify or not because its going to take me another few months to really get my head around these kinds of unix subjects